# retrieve property value of google map marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
  addMarker.setOptions({ draggable: true });
         google.maps.event.addListener(addMarker, 'dragend', function(event) {
         dragMarker(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng(), this.id);
         addMarker.setOptions({ draggable: false });
    });
```

**i wrote the above peice of code works fine but i want to add condition like this** 
if(addmarker.dragabble==true)
**i need to know the syntax to access the dragabble propery of the marker**

Comment: Read the [documentation on google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) `getDraggable() boolean` returns the current value of the draggable property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (addMarker.getDraggable()) {

    // Do something here
}
```